# Regular expression to obtain numbers and decimals

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to access

> 1.20163

from the following:

> 1 British Pound Sterling = 1.20163 Euro

So far I have:

```
$exchange['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[15]->description;
$rate = preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', '', $exchange['rate']);
```

However, this seems to returns

> 1 British Pound Sterling = 1.20163 Euro

Any ideas?

Comment: You're also confusing the parameters of [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: *(related)* [How to implement Exchange rates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973569/how-to-implement-exchange-rate-in-php/1973823#1973823)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you using preg_match wrong
You want to extract the value of 1.20163 from the string, right?
Then do this:

```
$s = '1 British Pound Sterling = 1.20163 Euro';
preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $s, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
```

You got your result in $result.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-9]{1,}$/
```

means you want to match a line containing only numbers. You wont get any match in your case. You also use preg_match in a wrong way. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php).

Try something like:

```
$exchange['rate'] = $xml->channel->item[15]->description;
preg_match('/=\s*([0-9.]+)\s/', $exchange['rate'], $matches);
// the result will be in $matches
$rate = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'/([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}) /'
```

Match numbers then decimal then numbers then space.