# how do I page scrape an exchange rate using PHP

Tags: php, currency, converters, web-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement exchange rate in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973569/how-to-implement-exchange-rate-in-php)

Im currently making a REST currency converter application for a project. I have made the majority of the program. currently I get my rates from yahoo finance which works fine. I have been asked by my lecturer to include another source for my rates in case the yahoo link goes down (just to be safe).

I have been told that a good way to do it would be to page scrape from the bloomblerg site

view-source:http://www.bloomberg.com/personal-finance/calculators/currency-converter/ 
line 1729 on has the exchange rates I need. 
How would I be able get the rate that I needed?

so I could have a function when I input GBP and it got the GBP to USD rate.

thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure how a page-scrape (something changes on the third party site, you're in trouble) can rate as a good 'back-up' measure?

Comment: @Nanne Most of the stuff they want to the project it silly. you should see some off the errors they want me to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

It is a very simple to use HTML Parser. Then for the function you want you could have

```
function converter($input_value)
{
  if ($input_value == "GBP")
     {
       //Do parse for GBP to USD
     }
  else
     {
       //Do parse for USD to GBP
     }

}
```

Comment: Tanks for the reply!! I will take a look at this tomorrow and report back :)